# Screen logs and launching script at boot (/profile.d vs /init.d)

Tags: bash, screen, init.d, shm

I had a script file (myScript.sh) with the following contents in /etc/profile.d with the to launch at start/reboot. It worked well - no issues.

```
#/bin/bash
screen -dmS p1 /home/pi/process1/process1d.sh
screen -dmS p2 /home/pi/process2/process2d.sh
```

Now, I realized that placing files in /etc/profile.d/ is when you want to launch the script when the user logs in, but this worked without that - why?

Now, I wanted to log the output of one of the processes and made some changes

```
#/bin/bash
screen -dmS p1 -L -Logfile /dev/shm/screen.p1 /home/pi/process1/process1d.sh
screen -dmS p2 /home/pi/process2/process2d.sh
```

On reboot, I only see that the 2nd process launched on boot, but not the first one. The 1st process launches only when I log in. I know this by the timestamp captured for these 2 processes.

So, it is confusion why the script worked in /etc/profile.d and doesn't work when I send the output of "screen" to a log file?

Any thoughts?